# How to implement the empty set - ∅?

Tags: java, null, set-theory

Assuming that you want to implement set theory concepts such as `element`, `set`, `collection` and `relation` in Java: How would you represent the *empty set* `∅`?

Do I mislead myself, if I think of the `NULL` concept as it is used by the three-valued logic of databases?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a unique answer to this question; it depends on what you want to achieve.  The obvious answer is "use an empty `Set`", but `NULL` might also be appropriate depending on what you're doing.

Comment: There are myriad ways to represent the empty set, depending on the intended application. `Set<E> = new HashSet<E>()` is one of the simplest.

Comment: Collections.emptySet() comes to mind ...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I'd say the absence of a set (you have zero sets), and an empty set (you have a set with zero elements) are not the same

Comment: A Set with no contents would work for me.  I would not represent it in Java will a null.  There could be some logic to this, but the code would be annoying since every time you referred to the collection you'd have to check for null.

Comment: @LukasEder I have never seen a case in my programming career where that distinction made a difference or was even helpful.

Comment: @TonyEnnis: Really?  No set and an empty set are pretty different...

Comment: @TonyEnnis: One example is lazy initialisation. The absence of the set means that it hasn't been initialised yet

Comment: @oli Perhaps mathematically.  While coding?  Never.  Now, if empty *must* be implemented as something distinct, I'd choose a method that didn't involve me scattering null checks all over my code.

Comment: @TonyEnnis: Think about [`java.util.File.list()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list()). It returns `null` if a file cannot provide its contained files (no set), or an empty array, if a file doesn't contain any files (empty set)...

Comment: @lukas I get it, but the practical difference is very slight.  In your example, I can't show files no matter how it fails.  In any event, I don't have a problem with a method returning a null versus an instance. However, the empty set IS a set (?right?) and assigning the null to some 'mySet' variable (which I believe is the use-case) would not be helpful at all.  I'd sooner see an instance that behaves like a null-set than just using a Java null.  In that regard, an empty Set would be more appropriate if mathematically imprecise.

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts. Now, I definitely know how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 52):

Use [`Collections.emptySet():`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptySet%28%29)

> Returns the empty set (immutable). This set is serializable. Unlike
>   the like-named field, this method is parameterized. This example
>   illustrates the type-safe way to obtain an empty set:
>
> ```
>  Set<String> s = Collections.emptySet();
> ```
>
> Implementation note: Implementations of this method need not create a separate Set object
>   for each call. Using this method is likely to have comparable cost to
>   using the like-named field. (Unlike this method, the field does not
>   provide type safety.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will use your advice.

Answer (score 16):

Using `null` to represent an empty set is a **bad idea**.  A `null` doesn't behave like a `Set` because (obviously) all attempts to perform an operation on it will throw a `NullPointerException`.  That means that if you use `null` to denote an empty set, you code will be littered with tests for `null` ... and if you miss one, you've got a bug.

The practical solution is to use `Collections.emptySet()` if you want an immutable empty set, or create an instance of the appropriate `Set` class (e.g. `new HashSet<>()`) if you want a mutable set that starts out empty.

---

On rereading the question, I realize that you may have meant something different to my original understanding.

If you were trying to implement / model mathematical set theory concepts in Java *from* scratch, you would probably implement `Set` as an immutable class.  (In mathematics, you don't mutate things!)  The empty set is then just a `Set` instance with no elements in it.  No special handling required.

The `NULL` concept is not required ... unless you are specifically trying to incorporate a "null", "undefined sets" or some similar concept in your mathematical model of sets.  (If you are, I'm not sure we can advise you without understanding your model ... from a mathematical perspective.)

Comment: +1 for stating why the null is a bad idea.